# Can MySQL convert a stored UTC time to local timezone?

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone, convert-tz

Can MySQL convert a stored UTC time to local time-zoned time directly in a normal select statement?

Let's say you have some data with a timestamp (UTC).

```
CREATE TABLE `SomeDateTable` (
  `id`    int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `value` float NOT NULL default '0',
  `date`  datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

Then when I

```
"select value, date from SomeDateTable";
```

I of course get all the dates as in their stored UTC form.

But let's say that I would like to have them in another timezone (with DST),
can I then add some magic to the select query so that I get all the dates back in the selected timezone?

```
"select value, TIMEZONE(date, "Europe/Berlin") from SomeDateTable";
```

Or must I do this in some other layer on top, like in some php code?
(it seems to be how most people have solved this problem).

---

If your MySQL installation allows you to use CONVERT_TZ it is a very clean solution,
this example shows how to use it.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ( '2010-01-01 12:00', 'UTC', 'Europe/Stockholm' )
```

However I don't know if this is a good way since some MySQL installation is missing this function, use with care.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yup, there's the [`convert_tz`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function.

Comment: Seems to be the correct thing but I hit this bug directly: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12445 my server was missing timezone data...

Comment: mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql

Answer (score 41):

For those unable to configure the mysql environment (e.g. due to lack of SUPER access) to use human-friendly timezone names like "America/Denver" or "GMT" you can also use the function with numeric offsets like this:

```
CONVERT_TZ(date,'+00:00','-07:00')
```

Comment: That will not work if that timezone has Daylight saving time (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/) since you will have different offset sommer and winter, and there is also some examples with 30min DST...

Comment: interesting.. in my case I have to run a few queries from PHP and don't want to do any TZ handling with the results in PHP, but I could easily alter the numeric value in the select query.  thanks

Answer (score 23):

One can easily use

```
CONVERT_TZ(your_timestamp_column_name, 'UTC', 'your_desired_timezone_name')
```

For example:

```
CONVERT_TZ(timeperiod, 'UTC', 'Asia/Karachi')
```

**Plus** this can also be used in WHERE clause to compare after the timezone is converted (but its always better to just compare in UTC timezones and convert to local timezone while displaying the timestamp)

```
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(timeperiod, 'UTC', {$this->timezone}) NOT BETWEEN {$timeperiods['today_start']} AND {$timeperiods['today_end']}
```

Comment: When I did your "WHERE CONVERT_TZ" query in mysql,  it did a whole table scan even though I used an indexed column for my 'timeperiod' and absolute timestamp values for 'Between start and end'. I've read that it's generally not a good idea to use column functions in a 'WHERE' or 'HAVING' clause.

Comment: You could be right but on the other side, if you donot use it in where class then how we are going to compare values?

Comment: Good point, and the only suggestion I have for that is to be very careful with the WHERE clause in order to minimize/mitigate tablespace scans. Partitioning the table on 'timeperiod' might be helpful in that area. Or, the server-side language could be used to do timezone conversion, but that's probably getting out of the realm of the OP's question.

Answer (score 14):

```
select convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+03:00')
```

For get the time only use:

```
time(convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+03:00'))
```

Answer (score 9):

## 1. Correctly setup your server:

On server, su to root and do this:

```
# mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql mysql
```

(Note that the **command** at the end is of course `mysql` , and, you're sending it to a **table** which happens to have the **same name**: `mysql`.)

Next, you can now `# ls /usr/share/zoneinfo` .

Use that command to see all the time zone info on ubuntu or almost any unixish server.

(BTW that's the convenient way to **find the exact official name of some time zone**.)

## 2. It's then trivial in mysql:

For example

```
mysql> select ts, CONVERT_TZ(ts, 'UTC', 'Pacific/Tahiti') from example_table ;
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| ts                  | CONVERT_TZ(ts, 'UTC', 'Pacific/Tahiti') |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 2020-10-20 16:59:57 | 2020-10-20 06:59:57                     |
| 2020-10-20 17:02:59 | 2020-10-20 07:02:59                     |
| 2020-10-20 17:30:08 | 2020-10-20 07:30:08                     |
| 2020-10-20 18:36:29 | 2020-10-20 08:36:29                     |
| 2020-10-20 18:37:20 | 2020-10-20 08:37:20                     |
| 2020-10-20 18:37:20 | 2020-10-20 08:37:20                     |
| 2020-10-20 19:00:18 | 2020-10-20 09:00:18                     |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

I propose to use

```
SET time_zone = 'proper timezone';
```

being done once right after connect to database. and after this all timestamps will be converted automatically when selecting them.

Comment: Important to note that this will not automatically convert DATE, TIME, and DATETIME fields.  This will only do automatic conversions for TIMESTAMP fields and affect the results of NOW() and CURDATE() functions.

Comment: If you want this to be permanent, you can also change the time_zone parameter.