# While selecting date from databse I want to add 5:30 to created_at date in the database

Tags: mysql

My Sql server existed in UTC. When I am selecting I want to get DATE to which `+5:30` is added.

```
select cl.ChangeStatus,cl.created_at from LogTable cl join  Table t on cl.Id=t.ID;


ChangeStatus     created_at
----------------------------------
submitted   2019-01-10 08:03:11
sent        2019-01-10 08:06:55
sent        2019-01-10 08:08:14
sent        2019-01-10 08:09:03
complete    2019-01-10 08:09:54 

ChangeStatus   created_at
--------------------------------
submitted   2019-01-10 12:33:11
sent        2019-01-10 12:36:55
sent        2019-01-10 12:38:14
sent        2019-01-10 12:39:03
complete    2019-01-10 12:39:54
```

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server related? Remove one tag which is not related.

Comment: Use Todatetimeoffset function to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry I added SQL Server by mistake, I'm currently using MySql

Comment: If its Mysql, try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187593/can-mysql-convert-a-stored-utc-time-to-local-timezone

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do the trick:

```
select
cl.ChangeStatus,
Todatetimeoffset(cl.created_at, '+5:30') as created_at
from LogTable cl
join  Table t on cl.Id=t.ID;
```