# Convert MySQL TIMESTAMP to another timezone during select

Tags: php, mysql

In my Mysql table date time is saving in TIMESTAMP (UTC) format, I want to convert it to another timezone. But I am getting NULL for following query

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('1575952663','UTC','Pacific/Kiritimati');
```

I tried another method

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME('1575952663'),'UTC','Pacific/Kiritimati');
```

but it is wrong time is getting because **FROM_UNIXTIME** converting from **Asia/Kolkata** because my mysql server timezone is **Asia/Kolkata**.
This query is running from php side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can MySQL convert a stored UTC time to local timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187593/can-mysql-convert-a-stored-utc-time-to-local-timezone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert\_tz returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454304/convert-tz-returns-null)

Comment: When i run the second command on sqlfiddle it returns `2019-12-10T18:37:43Z`. Is that the expected output? If so, the problem must be server side?

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME('1575952663'), @@SESSION.time_zone, 'Pacific/Kiritimati');` I would give this a try.

Comment: I feel like @Elby has not even searched for possible issues. ..

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid parameter for `convert_tz` based on [mysql time zone support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).

For `'Pacific/Kiritimati'`, it should `'+14:00'`.

```
convert_tz(from_unixtime(1575952663),'UTC','+14:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can convert it like below.**

CONVERT_TZ(date,'+00:00','-07:00');